# SQL Substring on varying column

Tags: sql, substring

I have a database table with a column `METADATA`. This `METADATA` may or may not contain a string. Here's the sample string:

```
StudentID:1234,StudentName:TestName,StudentNickName:TestNName,StudentLevel:5
```

Now, I want to extract the StudentNickName:TestName if it exists. Please note of the following constraint:

- `METADATA` column doesn't always contain a value
- `METADATA` column can contain a value without the `StudentNickName` clause
- The `StudentNickName:` is fixed, while the `TestNName` varies per row.

Comment: Where's the `METEDATA` column??

Comment: which database and version are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mssql 2005+

```
declare @t table(metadata varchar(200))
insert @t values('StudentID:1234,StudentName:TestName,StudentNickName:TestNName,StudentLevel:5')
insert @t values('')
insert @t values('StudentID:1234,StudentName:Thomas,StudentNickName:Tom,StudentLevel:3')


select left(b.a, patindex('%_,%', b.a)) StudentNickName
from @t t cross apply
(select right(metadata, patindex('%_:emaNkciNtnedutS%'
 , reverse('X'+ metadata)))+',' a) b
```

Result:

```
StudentNickName
---------------
TestNName

Tom
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in Sql Server

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(metadata VARCHAR(200))
INSERT @test VALUES('StudentID:1234,StudentName:TestName,StudentNickName:TestNName,StudentLevel:5')
INSERT @test VALUES('StudentID:1235,StudentName:TestName1,StudentNickName:TestNName1,StudentLevel:6')
INSERT @test VALUES('StudentID:1236,StudentName:TestName2,StudentNickName:TestNName2,StudentLevel:2')
INSERT @test VALUES('')

SELECT split.s.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') as colname FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST('<s>' + REPLACE(metadata,',','</s><s>') + '</s>' AS XML) col FROM @test
) AS t CROSS APPLY col.nodes('/s') AS split(s)
WHERE split.s.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') LIKE '%StudentNickName%'
```

Comment: this is also working fine, but I would prefer t-clausen.dk's solution. thanks a lot. ;)